# When I run this, I get "TypeError: Number is not a function"

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?")
var computerChoice = Math.random()
    if(computerChoice(0 < 0.33))  {
    computerChoice = ("Paper");
} else if(computerChoice(0.34 < 0.66)) {
    computerChoice = ("Rock");
} else {
    computerChoice = ("Scissors");
}
```

Is there something I'm missing in this code? It looks fine to me.. Anyway, as I said, when I run this, I get the TypeError mentioned above. I am trying to get Paper if the random number is below .33, and Rock if it is .34-.66, and Scissors if it is .67-1.

Comment: The error explains it all, you are using the variable `computerChoice` as a function (ie, `computerChoice(0 < 0.33)`) multiple times.

Comment: What do you think `computerChoice(0 < 0.33)` is supposed to do?

Comment: What is with the parenthesis around the string?

Comment: They keep the characters together and stop them drifting awaaaay…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use Math.random it will make the variable as Number and you trying to have it as a function.

Your code should look like this:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?")
var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if(computerChoice < 0.33)  {
    computerChoice = "Paper";
} else if(0.34 < computerChoice && computerChoice < 0.66) {
    computerChoice = "Rock";
} else {
    computerChoice = "Scissors";
}
```

where now you comparing the random number as A Number and not a function

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o95umhe4/1/)

Updated the code as per @Anthony Forloney

Comment: This worked! I had no idea the that you needed to arrange them as ( 0.34 < computerChoice < 0.66). Thanks a ton! (I know this was probably a dumb question, I just started taking a course on CodeAcademy yesterday and I am very new to this)

Comment: you are welcome @user3949811, no questions are dumb, please mark it as your answer if you find it working

Comment: I just did, I had to wait on the 15 minute timer to finish.

Comment: What about where *computerChoice* is `> 0.33` but `< 0.34`? There is no need for the first test in the *else..if* test.

Answer (score 1):

`var computerChoice = Math.random()`

creates a variable of the type Number. In your conditionals, you do:

`if(computerChoice(0 < 0.33))`

By adding parentheses after `computerChoice`, the JS interpreter thinks you are trying to call a function by that name, when really it's a Number.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the parentheses to get (computerChoice 0 < .33) and it is still giving me an error, except this is a syntax error (unexpected number)

Comment: You might want to tell the OP how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [conditional operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12) for this. Also, re–using variables is not considered a good idea, so:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?")
var num = Math.random();
var computerChoice = num < 0.33? "Paper" : num < 0.66? "Rock" : "Scissors";
```

Though rounding of decimals like that also slightly biases the result (but I don't think anyone will notice…)